# Get onChange event type

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, onchange

I have registered an onChange event to a comboBox in my form. I am trying to get the event type for example(item selected or key pressed) based on the event type other actions will be done. But I haven't managed to get this properties. Is it even possible? I am using Dojo 1.6!

```
searchEvent = dojo.connect(combo, 'onChange', function(event) {
        // console debug(event.type);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To listen for key-events, you can use dojo/keys.
Have a look : 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/keys.html (the old one) and here the new AMD : 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/keys.html

Please note that the old dojo.connect is deprecated an will sooner or later not work anymore. So if it is not a big problem for you, I would use the new AMD.

You can listen for the onKeypress like this(using dojo 1.8):

```
require(["dojo/keys","dojo/dom","dojo/on"], function(keys, dom, on){
on(dom.byId("exampleCombo"), "keypress", function(evt){
     alert(evt.charCode); //alerts the charCode of a letter or Number pressed
     alert(evt.keyCode); // alerts the keyCode of a key like ENTER
   });
 });
```

In this example the CharCode of the pressed key will be alerted.

To listen for the onChange of the Combobox you can do it like this

```
 require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on"], function (dom, on) {
 on(dom.byId("exampleCombo"), "change", function (evt) {
     alert('evt : '+JSON.stringify(evt.type));
 });
```

});

The alert shows : evt : 'change'.

Here's the fiddle for the Example above: http://jsfiddle.net/WPWv3/

For more information about events and their handling look here:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/events.html

Hope i could help you.

Regards, Miriam